# AsyncLayoutInflater with Webview

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-webview, layout-inflater

I was trying to use **`AsyncLayoutInflater`** with WebView, but inflation failed on the background thread:

```
Failed to inflate resource in the background! Retrying on the UI thread
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
```

I assume this means that WebView cannot be inflated asynchronously because it makes use of Handler internally, at least using **`AsyncLayoutInflater.`**

Is there any way around this?

Comment: asynchronous will be done only on Backgroud thread. Not in Main looper thread

Comment: You can see from the error message that it tries to fall back to the UI thread - `Retrying on the UI thread`. What's the complete stack trace?

Comment: Here is the complete stack trace: https://pastebin.com/sJNei4GY

Comment: Yeah, looks like you might not be able to do that. If I'm following the source correctly, it appears that the first attempt to inflate on the worker thread sets a static flag in a helper class that basically says "this UI thread `Handler` should've been created already". The second attempt on the UI thread fails because that `Handler` was never created. I didn't completely absorb the whole source, but it _might_ work it you inflate on a separate thread with a `Looper` setup.  If you're going to do that, though, you might as well ditch `AsyncLayoutInflater`, and roll your own.